# Excel 2010 highlight when 2 out of 3 columns in a row are duplicates

Tags: excel-2010

I need to highlight duplicate patients, so if 2 out of 3 columns are duplicates i want it to highlight.  At present with the normal duplicate rule, there are lots of duplicates showing as names are often common, so, column A Patient first name, B surname C nhs number, if the nhs number or either the first or surname is a duplicate I want it to highlight.  I've said 2 out of 3 to allow for spelling errors/anmomalies, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this small macro:

```
Sub NameChecker()

Dim N As Long, i As Long, j As Long, _
    v1 As String, v2 As String, v3 As String, _
    w1 As String, w2 As String, w3 As String, _
    Kount As Long

N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To N - 1
    v1 = Cells(i, 1)
    v2 = Cells(i, 2)
    v3 = CStr(Cells(i, 3))
    For j = i + 1 To N
        w1 = Cells(j, 1)
        w2 = Cells(j, 2)
        w3 = CStr(Cells(j, 3))
        Kount = -(v1 = w1) - (v2 = w2) - (v3 = w3)
        If Kount > 1 Then
            Range("A" & j & ":C" & j).Interior.ColorIndex = 27
        End If
    Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

Here is an example:

[image: demo]

The first entry has several near-duplicates.